# Use your fetch data from Mysql and reuse

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to use the fetch data from this

```
$employees=$user->viewEmployees();
```

And fetch it using

```
    <div style="position: relative;">
    <?php
     while ($employee = $employees->fetch()) { 
        $employee_name=$user->viewEmployeeUsingID($employee['id']);
        echo "<div id='div1' class='forDivision'>".$employee_name['employee_name']."</div>";
     } 
    echo "<div id='div1' id='forDivision' class='forDivision'>".$employee_name['id']."</div>";
     ?> 
  </div>
```

And reuse the object $employees to another whilelooping

```
<div style="position: relative; margin: 0px 0px 0px 200px; ">

    <?php
     while ($employee = $employee_winner->fetch()) { 
        $employee_name=$user->viewEmployeeUsingID($employee['id']);
        echo "<div id='div1' class='forLastname'>".$employee_name['employee_name']."</div>";

     } ?> 
    </div>
```

But error says

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: There are no more rows in the active result set. Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved.
```

What I did was to use another variable $employees2 but my main dillema is im using this script (Random) query generator, so what happen is the query is not generating a consistent report, any idea or work around that needed ?

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM employees ORDER BY NEWID()");
```

Comment: you can write the records into an array in first loop. Or use `fetchAll` to retrieve them all at once and re-use that resulting array.

Comment: @Jeff got it thanks man, do I need to delete these post ?

Comment: you could, yes.

Comment: $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)